# How to get rid of keyboard when user taps background (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss keyboard by touching background of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview)

I have a custom UIScrollView which contains UITableView and UITextView. When user clicks on text field, keyboard pops up and it also disappears when user presses Return key on keyboard.

**Question:** How to get rid of keyboard when user taps on UITableView? No matter what I try, I just can't catch any touch events... Using iPhone 3.0 SDK since that does seem to make a big difference. As far as I understand touch events are not automatically redirected to... anywhere! Still there are touch events, since I can scroll table view up/down, even I don't want to!

What do I have to do to dismiss keyboard, when user presses somewhere else but keyboard itself or the text field?

Comment: Check out the anser for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038); it uses a very simple gesture recognizer to do what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)_indexPath {
    if ([self.textView isFirstResponder])
        [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
    //...
}
```

Comment: It works! Don't know what to say, I'm overwhelmed... :D Ok, could you also please explain why does it work? Really curious! I tried earlier e.g. selectRowAtIndexPath, which was never called. What's this "tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView" magical thing and under what circumstances can it be used?

Comment: the "if([self.textView isFirstResponder]) is not necessary since resignFirstResponder will do nothing if it is not the first responder and will get rid of the keyboard if it is the first responder.

Comment: That doesn't appear work if there is no row where they're tapping, ie. the TableView isn't full. How do you detect if they tap on the TableView itself?