# Objective-C, how to Generally resignFirstResponder?

Tags: ios, objective-c

(my boss says) that I have to implement a "Done" button on a navBar so that the various items in the view (that contain an edit box) will dismiss their keyboard (if they were in focus).

It seems that I must iterate through all items and then call resignFirstResponder on each on the off-chance that one of them is in focus? This seems a bit messy (and hard to maintain if e.g. someone else adds more items in future) - is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found it!

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview)

I discovered that all I need do is this:-

```
-(void) done {
    [[self.tableView superview] endEditing:YES];
}
```

// also [self.view endEditing:YES]; works fine

[remark]
Also I learn how to do the equivalent of an "eventFilter" to stop UITableViewController from swallowing background touch events by intercepting them *before* they get there - from the same, wonderful post on that thread - see  "DismissableUITableView".
[end of remark]

Comment: A minor gotcha here, the BOOL argument for `-endEditing:` actually determines whether or not the view will be forced to resign first responder status. Forcing this on a view means that `-canResignFirstResponder` will not be sent to the view. Use `[self.view endEditing:NO];` for the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate through the controls since only one can be first responder at the moment.

This will reset the responder to the Window itself:
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:nil]

Comment: Thanks Gobra.

I get an "unrecognized selector..." error - this object is a UITableViewController and that inherits from UIResponder and neither have that window() method?

Comment: I have suggested solution for MacOS, not iOS (tags). I'm not sure whether UI-classes have similar method.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a currentTextField Object,

In .h file have an instance variable as

```
UITextField *currentTextField;
```

Now in .m file.

Note : Dont forget to set the delegates of all the textField to this class

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   currentTextField = textField;
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   currentTextField = nil;
}
```

Now in your button action method

```
-(IBAction)buttonTap
{
    if([currentTextField isFirstResponder])
        [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This avoids iterating through all the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to handle it by searching all subviews of main view with recursive function, check example below

```
- (BOOL)findAndResignFirstResponder {
if (self.isFirstResponder) {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        if ([subView findAndResignFirstResponder]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

and also you can put this method to your utility class and can use from tap gesture. All you have to do is simply adding to gesture to view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideEverything)];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and than you can call hideEverything method;

```
- (void) hideKeyboard {
    [self.view findAndResignFirstResponder];
    ...
    ...
}
```