# How to dismiss an UITextView with tapping outside?

Tags: iphone

I've got a bit of a doubt with `UITextView`s. I use to put `UITextField`s, and remove the keyboard by tapping outside with the faithful old:

```
-(void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        [view resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

I have this UITextView which is set on my view (and actually is `self.myTV`, to be precise), and I do the following

```
-(void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
        [view resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Same as above, save for the different class...

Well it doesn't seem to work. Anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that UITextView is not FirstResponder in your case as per the subview hierarchy of your app.

I would suggest you to categorize UIView to find the first responder as under: 
    This category on UIView, which calls on the UIWindow and traces for the first responder.

```
@implementation UIView (FindAndResignFirstResponder)
- (BOOL)findAndResignFirstResponder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;     
    }
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        if ([subView findAndResignFirstResponder])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: Categorizing UIView seems a bit overkill, then every single UIView in my app also has that behavior. I'd be afraid of having something, somewhere, that starts misbehaving and taking ages to trace it back.

Comment: I'll probably end up, unless someone else has a better solution, accepting your answer which seems technically true though I voiced my problem with it. What I did in the end was to commit the content of the textview in the viewWillDisappear method, and put said view inside a navigationController (so I get a button to press to go back to the normal flow of my app). It actually feels better to use anyway than what I initially had in mind. I guess that if it feels unnatural to code, it's because I'm not doing it right UI-wise, often ;)

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to resign first responder for any subview that is currently the first responder is:

```
[self.view endEditing:NO];
```

Or if you want to force the first responder to resign without asking it first:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```