# How do I make the keyboard go away when a user clicks on the background of the view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UITextField in my iOS app. When a user enters text and clicks Return, the keyboard goes away due to a call to an IBAction with "resignFirstResponder."

However, XCode does not let me drag a line from the UIView itself to File Owner. How do I associate touching the background of a UIView with an IBAction that makes the keyboard go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already noticed that you can't drag from the UIView to the file's owner to assoctiate an action with a touch.

The way to work around this is to change the class of the background view from `UIView` to `UIControl` and hook up an action from there to a method in your controller to stop editing.

That's because a UIControl can respond to touch events, and a UIView does not, but a UIControl  subclasses UIView, and so it can be used in place of a UIView.

I wrote an [example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip) a while ago that uses this technique. Have a look at the `secondViewController`'s xib file and see how I've change the class of the background view and hooked it up to a an action in the controller to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 10):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer. see: [Dismiss keyboard by touching background of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview)

so instead of tableview, just add it to your view instead:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)] autorelease];
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //so that action such as clear text field button can be pressed
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and have a method to hide your keyboard

```
- (void) hideKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the touchesBegan with Event and end editing on the view:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  [self.view endEditing:YES];

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

One easy way to do it is to create a big transparent UIButton behind the view.

Comment: lol, this is indeed a funny solution. (PD: not down voting you or anything tho)