# dismiss keyboard when anything except UISearchBar is touched

Tags: ios, keyboard, xcode5

Is there anyway to do this? I have tried all kinds of elaborate suggestions here on SO. The objective is simple: if I click anywhere outside a specific view, here a search view, I want the keyboard to go away. Thanks for any help.

Comment: what did you try to do for it?

Comment: I tried the stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield?rq=1; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview

Comment: Could you show your code?