# UIKeyboard appearing triggers a scroll event that then dismisses the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I've got a strange problem that I've been unable to solve.

I have a text field in a TableViewCell in a TableView. When I tap the cell a keyboard appears. I have the following code to dismiss said keyboard:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self findAndResignFirstResonder:self.view];
}
```

The problem is, when a TextField is below where the top of the keyboard would be, the TableView scrolls so it is visible. This in turn triggers the scrollViewDidScroll method, which then dismisses the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes sense -- the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:` is called *every time* the tableview is scrolled. So if your `scrollViewDidScroll:` dismisses the keyboard, then when the app automatically adjusts(scrolls) the tableview content offset to account for the keyboard, it dismisses itself.

You're going to want to implement your keyboard dismissing differently. For one solution, make your UITableViewController a `UITextFieldDelegate`. Then, implement `textFieldShouldReturn:` in which you can call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` or `[self.view endEditing:YES]` (see [Managing the Keyboard (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) for more details).

I imagine the effect you were looking for was that the keyboard would be dismissed if the user touched anywhere outside of the UITextField or keyboard. For that I would look at implementing `touchesBegan:` (as described in [Techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_7_Code_to_Hide_the_Keyboard)) or with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`(as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview), just be sure to include `gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` as it suggests a little further down in the page).