# How to dismiss keyboard in a tableView after typing in textview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, uikeyboard

In my app I have a `UITableView`, which includes in its first cell a `UITextView` and in the other cells just `UILabel`s.

How can I dismiss the keyboard after typing something in the `UITableView`? I want to dismiss it anytime I tap on the other cells or scroll the tableview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView with return key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)

Comment: no it's not the same question. Return key in UITextView is for new line and I want it that way. I need to dismiss the keyboard when I start scrolling the UITableView or when tapping on anywhere outside the UITextView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4132774/4475605

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `UITableViewDelegate` which conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` to implement:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     dismissKeyboard()
}

func dismissKeyboard(){
     self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Add to viewDidLoad:
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

//Or since you wanted to dismiss when another cell is selected use:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
     dismissKeyboard()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the easiest and simplest way How I am doing this via IB.

[image: Dismiss keyboard property]
Here you can set property as you want

or if you want via programming then

```
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Comment: This worked for me : By code self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;

Comment: self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag