# TableView taps fail after gesture to dismiss keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This failure of Apple to allow user to dismiss keyboard is taking its toll...

I have managed to add code to do this on a few views but now I have a ViewController with a TextView and a couple of TableViews.

After I use a Tap Gesture Recognizer to dismiss the keyboard, the taps on the table cells don't trigger. The code is as follows.

```
func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.view!.tag != 33 {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        titleView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

This might be belt & braces but I was trying to see if/what might work. (Tag 33 is the actual TextView)

The table cell is triggered in the usual way and without the tap gesture code it works fine.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)....
```

An IBAction tap on a button seems to work but not the cell trigger.

Comment: Should this be tag == 33?

Comment: think is ok - don't want the tap inside the textview to end the editing. This was added on previous views to deal with the keyboard but works fine - the resignFirstResponder fires perfectly, just that after that the taps on the table cells are somehow blocked (maybe cos they are trying to resign a textview that is already resigned?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case here, the process of posting a question leads to a self-answer....

If using TableView cell taps (and I guess in general), add the following line to the gesture setup.

```
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

The solution in more detail can be found here.
[Dismiss keyboard by touching background of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Hey @RobertyBob adding gesture recognizer does not allow to execute did selectRowForIndex Path.
To dismiss keyboard on I would suggest you to add code to your controller file.
Note that: Conform Protocol UITextFieldDelegate and set all textfields.delegate  = self.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

**Another Best way**
1. Select TextField
2. Goto attribute inspector and choose keyboard type to default and Return Key to Done