# How to dismiss keyboard on ALL textField?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to dismiss keyboard without referencing the UITextField outlet one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3.x Use this:**

```
self.view.endEditing(true) //when you are using a view
self.tableView.endEditing(true) //when you are a table-view
```

The view will resign the keyboard from all child.
You call it when a user touches the table or view.

Comment: if it is in inside the tableview or scrollview  your answer will work ..?

Comment: no , if it is in scrollview then use `self.scrollview.endEditing(true)`

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview

Answer (score -1):

This is how I use it, when allowing the user to tap on the view to dismiss the keyboard

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

And than create a function like below

```
@objc func handleTap() {
   view.endEditing(true)
}
```