# iOS-Objective-C: Keyboard not getting dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

In my iOS application, on "More Information Screen" I have 10-12 `UITextField` to get user information.

User needs to type all information except "State".

When user clicks on "State" `UITextField >> New UITableViewController` is pushed.

Everything works fine, but when user clicks on "State" field "`Keyboard`" should get dismissed which is opened due to other fields like "City", "Address".

[image: enter city.]
[image: state view]

For this I have added "`Tag = 1`" to "State" `UITextfield`, When user clicks on "State" field keyboard should get dismissed and new view should get loaded.

I have added following code but no luck:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(textField.tag == 1){
        [txtCity resignFirstResponder];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        //load state listing
        SelectStateProvince *selectStateProvince = [[SelectStateProvince alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        selectStateProvince.parentViewName = @"Respondent";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectStateProvince animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview

Comment: verify textfield tag is set to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the below implementation.. Move the code to show the picker to should begin delegate..

```
   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if(textField.tag == 1){
            //load state listing
            SelectStateProvince *selectStateProvince = [[SelectStateProvince alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            selectStateProvince.parentViewName = @"Respondent";
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectStateProvince animated:YES];
            return false
        } else {
           return true
        }
    }
```